# Как раскрасить TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте, подскажите как изменять цвет у строк или определеной ячейки в таблице?
В swing это было легко сделать при помощи Render'a,а вот в javafx непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет
Для того, чтобы поменять цвет строк, тебе необходимо передать в твою таблицу rowFactory, в котором, в реализации метода onUpdate, ты напишешь логику, которая будет менять цвет.

Comment: Но все еще не понятно как задать цвет например: каждой 2-й строке или произвольной ячейке.

Comment: Ответ конечно запоздал, но тогда тебе надо, чтобы у тебя в каждой ячейке лежало что-то типо Label, у которого ты и будешь изменять цвет в определенных случаях